# cron job in centos7 for pythonscript

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

I   want to schedule  a  cron job  in centos7   to run a ".py" script every day at a given  time  that  needs   to  output  on the   console.  The   script takes  4   input from the   user

```
import sys
import os
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
import pysftp
from glob import glob
import datetime
import shutil
import git
from itertools import izip_longest
import filecmp
import getpass  

def main(): 


    prod_path = raw_input("Enter the ABSOLUTE PATH  where you wish to download  Prod  files  and folders: ")
    git_path= raw_input("Enter the ABSOLUTE PATH  where you wish to download GIT  files  and folders: ")
    known_hosts_path=raw_input("Enter the ABSOLUTE PATH of the known_hosts file:")
    p=getpass.getpass("Enter the Password for Production server:")
```

Since   it   should   be scheduled in windows  as well  I have  used the   followowing

```
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
    raw_input("\n Press enter  to quit")
```

to prevent automatic exit  in windows

How   do I need  to  edit crontab  to   accommodate    these?

Note:

which python  returns me

```
/usr/bin/python
```

I tried the   following :

```
12 15 * * * /usr/bin/python /root/prodgit.py -prod_path /root/prod -git-path /root/git -known_hosts_path /root/known_hosts.txt -p xxxx
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? If so, what are you using?

Comment: You won't be able to use cron successfully to schedule jobs that require input from a user at a keyboard. Cron is intended for unattended, scheduled jobs. Whilst, in theory, you could make a terminal public read and enable the script to read from it, you would have to rely on it being unused for anything else as your cron script will just steal input from whatever else is going on.

Comment: Use the `argparse` module to parse command-line arguments, instead of prompting. Or you could do both: check if there are command-line arguments, if not you can prompt for them.

Comment: yes I am using centos7 VM

Comment: Thanks Barmar, will try the   argparse option. Thought Linux  had more options than Windows